# SDN4 Neo4j inheritance and index declaration at base class

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

This is my SDN 4 entities:

```
@NodeEntity
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Index(unique = false)
    private Date createDate;

....

}

@NodeEntity
public class Decision extends BaseEntity {  

....

}
```

This is `:schema` output:

```
Indexes
   ON :BaseEntity(createDate) ONLINE
```

and I have a following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (d:Decision) WHERE d.createDate={createDate}
```

AFAIK ([Neo4j SDN4 entity inheritance and indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897865/neo4j-sdn4-entity-inheritance-and-indexes)) this way Neo4j index `:BaseEntity(createDate)` will not be used because I'm trying to reach d node on :Decision label.

Is there any way at SDN 4 to define index via class inheritance(leave `createDate` at `BaseEntity` level) in order to be able to use `createDate` index on `:Decision` label ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the query is *a derived finder* then it is related to [this issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/367). The only way to work around this now is to use a custom `@Query`.

If the query is a custom `@Query` you just need to use the correct label in the query, note that you can use multiple labels:

```
MATCH (d:Decision:BaseNode) 
WHERE d.createDate={createDate}
```

The planner should be smart enough to do the right thing and use the index, nevertheless you should verify that using `PROFILE`. If not use the `USING INDEX` hint:

```
MATCH (d:Decision:BaseNode) 
USING INDEX d:BaseNode(createDate)
WHERE d.createDate={createDate}
```